# How to fix cross-env issue when running "npm run dev" for vue-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli

When I run `npm run dev`, I can not get the local IP properly.

> Error: listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument 0.0.0.0:8081

I do.
1. delete the "cross-env" folder and the "cross-spawn" folder under the node_modules
 
2. run `npm install` 
3. run `npm run dev`
4. the error ip changes as follows.

> Error: listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument 10.0.75.1:8081

the ip address is vEthernet for the docker.

```sh
PS E:\WorkSpace\my-project> npm run dev

> my-project@1.0.0 dev E:\WorkSpace\my-project
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

E:\WorkSpace\my-project\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:356
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument 10.0.75.1:8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1279:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1460:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-project@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-11T13_23_46_070Z-debug.lo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try this:

```
yarn remove webpack-dev-server
yarn add webpack-dev-server@2.9.1 --dev
yarn run dev
```

or using npm instead yarn

Comment: @vine-nam did it work? If it did, please up-vote my answer :)